# How to get the total number of nodes updated in a neo4j query?

Tags: python, neo4j

After I run a cypher query in python, I would like to get the count of nodes updated through the query. How do I go about it?

Comment: Which client library do you use?

Comment: neo4jrestclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Neo4j Bolt Driver 1.6 for Python, you need the function `consume`:

```
print(session.run("MERGE (a:TEST {name: rand()})").consume().counters)

// {'labels_added': 1, 'nodes_created': 1, 'properties_set': 1}
```

**Update**: If you use the old library [`neo4jrestclient`](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client) (no longer actively developed), then use the variable [`stats`](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queries.html#query-statistics)(and specify the option `data_contents=True`):

```
print(gdb.query("MERGE (a:TEST {name: rand()})", data_contents=True).stats)
// {u'relationship_deleted': 0, u'constraints_added': 0, u'labels_added': 1, 
// u'labels_removed': 0, u'nodes_created': 1, u'properties_set': 1, u'nodes_deleted': 0, 
// u'constraints_removed': 0, u'indexes_removed': 0, u'contains_updates': True, 
// u'relationships_created': 0, u'indexes_added': 0}
```

Comment: How do I use session?

Comment: How do I incorporate session in python code? Name session is not defined.

Comment: query2= "match(a:iknode) match(d:flights12)-[r]-(e:flights12) where type(r) = a.name set a.some_flag = some_flag"
db.query(query)